# How should I call rand.range again if my random number equals 0?

Tags: python

Im making a guessing game the tells the user to guess a random number 1-100. I want to generate a random number with a random multiple, that is within 1-100. If I adjust the `rand.range` to `(1,100,ran_num)` it messes it all up. How should I confirm the random number isn't zero and if it is call `rand.range` again? My teacher says I should keep the range between 0-100 and add some code to confirm it isn't zero. I think I need to add an "if statement" but i'm not sure how to. Thanks!!!

```
import random
ran_num=(random.randint(2,10))

print("Hello the goal of the game is to guess a multiple-of-",ran_num, "number", "that is between 1-100.")  

answer = random.randrange(0,101,ran_num)
```

Comment: use a function and a conditional

Comment: If you don't want `0` why not `random.randrange(ran_num, 101, ran_num)`? Using `1` "messes it all up" (please give a [mre] when asking) because your first valid value _isn't always 1_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want the range to be 1-100 but with a random multiple between 1-10. My teacher says I should keep the range between 0-100 and add some code to confirm it isn't zero. I think I need to add an "if statement" but i'm not sure how to.

Comment: What does "a random number with a random multiple" even mean?  A random number within [1, 100] range, divisible by random single-digit number?

Comment: @KlasŠ. Yes. It's a guessing game that choses a random number within 1-100 and divisible by a random number 2-10. Ex. It will tell the user to guess a multiple-of-7 number and the answer will be 49. Then if changes every round.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

```
rand_mul = random.randint(2, 10)
rand_int = random.randrange(r1, 101, r1)
```